# Is it possible to store methods in JSON, like how a pickle file does?

Tags: python, json, pickle

I am trying to store some data as an object representation. In the object I have defined some methods. I am thinking of using pickle files to store the objects, as it is computationally expensive to compute the data everytime. I was wondering if the same is possible with JSON as well. For my purpose, I assume the said JSON files will be loaded and reused with python scripts only, so the question of method reuse in other languages does not arise.

I would like to do the same because I would like the data to be in human readable form, as I collaborate with non-programmers whom I often need to present the data with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [JSON](http://json.org/) specification. It is really simple.

JSON is only about data. You could decide that some of the data is some particular [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) for some particular [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) (so it could be Python bytecode, if you want it to be so). But that is only *your convention*.

The question "is it meaningful for you to do so" is a different one. At least, you want to be sure that the bytecode you want to store (as some JSON string) would be understood identically on both ends.

But then, why use JSON? Just use your usual Python pickling...